# Change Build Controller From One Server To Another For A Collection

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I noticed that a new collection that I have been told to use at work uses the wrong build controller.  I found this out by going to the "Manage Build Controllers" window.  Another collection we have uses a build controller that has all the necessary software on there and I would like that to be the build controller for both collections.

The Manage Build Controllers window only allows me to Remove a controller.  But how do I assign the other build controller to the collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A build controller can only be used for a team project collection. It cannot be shared among collections.

To register a build controller to a collection, you will need to logon the build machine where the build controller is installed, open the Team Foundation Administration Console and go to Build Configuration section, select to Unregister the build service host if it is currently registered to another team project collection, and register it to the desired team project collection.

This link provides you several topics about configuring your build system, including creating and registering build controllers and build agents:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181711.aspx

Build configuration cannot be done via Visual Studio.

Hope this helps.